# (window: onbeforeunload) = "onUnload ($ event)" is not working

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the function onbeforeunload to detect the closing of the browser window, but when I close this it does not execute the confirmation function.
I am using angular 2.

```js
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private router: Router,
    private _fireBase: AngularFireDatabase) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.router.events.subscribe((evt) => {
      if (!(evt instanceof NavigationEnd)) {
        return;
      }
      window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    });
  }

  onUnload(event) {
    console.log('funciona', event);
    confirm('desea salir');
  }
}
```

```html
<div  (window:onbeforeunload)="onUnload($event)">
    <app-navbar></app-navbar>
    <div class="main-body">
        <div class="page-wrapper">
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
            <app-login></app-login>
        </div>
    </div>
    <app-footer></app-footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the following way:

```
 @HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
 doSomething($event) {
   $event.returnValue= true;
 }
```

But please pay attention that according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload)

> To combat unwanted pop-ups, some browsers don't display prompts created in beforeunload event handlers unless the page has been interacted with. Moreover, some don't display them at all.

In my case on Chrome a pop will show only when Developer Tools Console is opened (Inspect mode).